# Fetching specific Fields from my Firebase Database

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to fetch a specific field from my Firebase database in a function. I have a snapshot of the document and the document ID that gets imported from the screen before, where the user can press on a note. I don't understand how to get a specific Field value. My application always crashes if I use a document snapshot and I don't know why.

I tried to to it all in my build function, because that was recomended in other Stack Overflow Questiones, but I weirldy couldn't use my document Id in my build function. I would be very happy if you could help me fix this problem, thank you!
Here is my Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class ShowNoteView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String documentId;
  const ShowNoteView({Key? key, required this.documentId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShowNoteViewState createState() => _ShowNoteViewState();
}

class _ShowNoteViewState extends State<ShowNoteView> {

  String jobText = 'failed';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchNoteData(widget.documentId, jobText);
  }

  Future<String> fetchNoteData(String documentId, String jobText) async {
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notes');
    var docSnapshot = await collection.doc(documentId).get();
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
    Map<String, dynamic>? data = docSnapshot.data();
    var value = data?['textJob']; 
    jobText = value;
    setState((){});
}
return '';
    

    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'notes'
        ),
        actions: [],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(jobText),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Firestore:

[image: Firestore screenshot]

Comment: You accessed the field with `data?['textJob']`, while the field in Firestore is `jobText`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're attempting to fetch data from Firestore based on a document ID and display a specific field value in your Flutter app. Your approach is mostly correct, but there are a couple of issues in your code.

First, the reason why your application crashes is likely due to the fact that you're accessing the jobText variable before it's initialized. In your initState method, you're calling fetchNoteData method, which is asynchronous, and immediately accessing jobText afterward. Since fetchNoteData hasn't completed yet, jobText remains 'failed', causing potential issues.

Second, you're passing jobText as a parameter to fetchNoteData, but you're not actually using the updated value from the function inside the build method.

Here's a revised version of your code:

```
class ShowNoteView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String documentId;
  const ShowNoteView({Key? key, required this.documentId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShowNoteViewState createState() => _ShowNoteViewState();
}

class _ShowNoteViewState extends State<ShowNoteView> {
  String jobText = 'Loading...'; // Initial value

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchNoteData(widget.documentId);
  }

  Future<void> fetchNoteData(String documentId) async {
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notes');
    var docSnapshot = await collection.doc(documentId).get();
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      setState(() {
        jobText = docSnapshot.data()?['textJob'] ?? 'No data'; // Update jobText with the fetched value
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        jobText = 'Document not found';
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Notes'),
        actions: [],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(jobText),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```